# List vs Tuple sort performance

Tags: python, performance, list, tuples

first of all I realize that this has been covered before. And second my programming experience is extremely limited. However since I was so surprised to see such an increase in performance, and since I also have it relatively well benchmarked I thought that I would share the results.

Basically what I am doing is k-means clustering on a mesh on Rhinoceros with a script in Python (IronPython). [Here](http://api.ning.com/files/EDPpnAInkDu0lodf8jefHCjkLFBKJMz2BYkLsE%2aQzPdh8OeAEbKQk0hOlhVQahYDLsyfysdLT9comWtkNRV1Yad-j3XPZhVq/VSA.png) is a screenshot of the results. And bellow is a benchmark of all the functions in my script.

```
CYCLE  4
GetProxy =  20.0
GetProxySeed =  10.0
BuildQueue =  0.0
AssignToRegion =  610.0009
SplitRegion =  10.0
RenumberSplitRegions =  30.0
FindAdjacentRegions =  10.0
FindRegionsToCombine =  130.0002
ReCombineRegions =  0.0
RenumberRegions =  0.0
ReGrowSeeds =  110.0002
CYCLE  4 TOOK =  940.0013
AssignToRegionTime Average over all cycles (20)=  613.8351
```

It can clearly be seen that AssignToRegion is the bottleneck. This is the function that assigns each face in the mesh to a cluster. Bellow is a "pseudo-code" of the steps involved:

```
It starts with a queue of structure [ [ error value, region index tag, face index] , ...] 
equal in length to the number of regions. Then:

1. Pop item of least error. 
2. Check if item has already been assigned to a region. 
3. If not, append to the region of same tag. 
4. Get adjacent faces minus faces already assigned to a region. 
5. Update queue with new faces.
5.1. Get error of new faces. This basically compared the face's normal vector to the region's normal vector. The greater the
difference, the greater the error. 
5.2. Add tag of last popped face. 
5.3. Sort queue.

Repeat until queue is empty.
```

I got more than **x2 increase in performance** just by *changing each list in the queue* [ [ error value, region index tag, face index] , ...], *into tuples* [ ( error value, region index tag, face index)  , ...] , though I don't really understand why the change is so dramatic.

```
CYCLE  4
GetProxy =  21.0012
GetProxySeed =  8.0004
BuildQueue =  1.0001
AssignToRegion =  245.014
SplitRegion =  5.0003
RenumberSplitRegions =  32.0019
FindAdjacentRegions =  6.0004
FindRegionsToCombine =  114.0065
ReCombineRegions =  0.0
RenumberRegions =  0.0
ReGrowSeeds =  99.0057
CYCLE  4 TOOK =  553.0317
AssignToRegionTime Average over all cycles (20)=  275.21574
```

For those curious, bellow is the code of the whole function. The aforementioned change is at the very end.

Other suggestions that might speed things up are more than welcomed!

```
def AssignToRegion(faceNormals, vertices, faceVertexIndexes, areaFaces, adjacentFaces, regions, queue, assignedIndexes):
    ## queue = [ [error, regionIndex, index], ... ]
    ## OR queue= [ (error, regionIndex, index), ... ]

    ## Container list for the items popped from the priority list.
    assignedIndexes = set(assignedIndexes)
    ## Until the priority queue is not empty, keep popping 
    ## the item with least priority from the priority queue. 

    while queue :
        mostPriority = queue.pop()
        faceIndex =  mostPriority[2]

        ## If the index of the popped face has already 
        ## been assigned skip to the next one. 
        if faceIndex not in assignedIndexes:
            regionIndex = mostPriority[1] ## regionIndex is Int
            regions[regionIndex][1].append(faceIndex)
            assignedIndexes.add(faceIndex)
            ## Get the adjacent faces of the popped face
            ## and append them to the priority queue. 
            newAdjacentFaces = set(adjacentFaces[faceIndex])
            ## If an adjacent face has already been assigned
            ## to a region, skip it. 
            newAdjacentFaces -= assignedIndexes
            ## Append faces to priority queue.
            queue = UpdateQueue( regions[ regionIndex] , faceNormals, areaFaces, queue, newAdjacentFaces)

    return (regions)


def UpdateQueue( region, faceNormals, areaFaces, queue, newFaces ):
    regionIndex = region[0]
    proxyNormal = region[4]

    newFacesErrors = MetricError(regionIndex, newFaces, faceNormals, areaFaces, proxyNormal)
    queue.extend( newFacesErrors )
    ## This appears faster thatn queue.sort
    queue = sorted(queue, reverse = True)
    ## This returns a list queue = [ [error, regionIndex, index] , [...] ]
    return queue

def MetricError(regionIndex, faceIndexes, faceNormals, areaFaces, proxyNormal):
    errors = []

    for index in faceIndexes:
            area = areaFaces[index]
            normal = faceNormals[index]
            normalError = normal - proxyNormal

            ## This can be obtained as an attribute of the vector
            ## and it's much faster.
            # moduleNormalError = (normalError[0] ** 2 + normalError[1] ** 2 + normalError[2] ** 2)
            moduleNormalError = normalError.SquareLength
            error = moduleNormalError * area
            errors.append( [error, regionIndex, index] )
            ## OR
            errors.append( (error, regionIndex, index) )

    ## This returns a list errors = [ [error, regionIndex, index], ... ]
    ## OR errors = [ (error, regionIndex, index), ... ]
    return errors
```

As suggested by @user2357112, using heapq I get:

```
AssignToRegionTime average of 20 cycles =  135.80836
```

Comment: That's cause tuple is unmutable and list is mutable.

Comment: @Denis -- I'm not sure that really answers the question.  Of course, the answer to this question is definitely non-obvious (at least to me).

Comment: Can you run this with Cpython, or PyPy (or Jython, ...) and see if you still have the same performance discrepancy?

Comment: @Denis Yeah I kinda know that. But I still don't have a deep knowledge as to why the change is so great.

Comment: @mgilson -- Unfortunately I can't run in on PyPy. At least not that I am aware of.

Comment: If you need a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), I suggest [heapq](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).

Comment: @user2357112 -- Never heard of heapq, Thanks. It seems to be a separate module. I guess first I'll have to get it to work on Rhino.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Using heapq I get AssignToRegion = 120 and AssignToRegionTime average over all cycles (20)  = 135.50776   .Thanks! That's almost an order of magnitude better than using lists.